# php undefined variable warning for function argument

Tags: php, function

I receive an "undefined variable" warning on the variable that is passed as a function argument

Here is the code:

```
function myFunction ($var) {
... code...
for (k=0; k<$var; k++){
}
...code...
Return $something;
}
```

Later:

```
echo myFunction(5);
```

Strangely the code works, produces the expected output, but also produces this warning.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you actually using `k`, or `$k`?

Comment: I have a feeling you haven't decided whether you use `$` or not.

Comment: Translate `undefined variable` for me please -.-

Comment: Please provide a complete, runnable example that reproduces this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong `for (k=0; k<$var; k++){` you are missing the `$` in front of the variable

It should be something like this

```
 for ($k=0; $k < $var; $k++){
```

You also need to have defined `$var` for more information see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

This is not javascript, always put a $ before each variable :)

```
for ($k = 0; $k < $var; $k++)
```

And instantiate your $something you are returning.

Comment: Sorry I made the mistake only here in the posting. The error I asked about disappeared without changing the code so it must have been something cached... Thanks again